# How can I verify that my laptop does not have malware in the firmware?

Tags: malware, attack-vector, firmware, flash-memory

I purchased a used laptop on eBay. 
I scrubbed the hard disk to make sure there were no lingering or unknown viruses left on the disk and then installed fresh Windows 10.

But, what about the firmware?

Does Windows Update make legitimate updates to the firmware?

Is there a way to detect that the firmware contains unauthorized  modifications?

Is there a way to re-write the flash firmware with factory fresh content?

Comment: 1) Don't worry about it. 2) No. 3) No. 4) Maybe (check with the manufacturer), except that modified firmware could pretend to flash the firmware while remaining unchanged

Comment: You can't prove a negative.  As Conor implies, there's always something else to be worried about if you're paranoid enough.  In practice, firmware compromises are stuff that you might worry about if you're an intelligence agency, or do Top Secret work.

Comment: @ConorMancone 2) yes, they do – windows update includes driver updates, and updated drivers sometimes also update firmware components.

Comment: Look into SRTM, which is able to verify, with some effort, firmware on a system with a TPM.

Comment: there's a 99.99% chance it does not, and if it did, there's a 99.99% chance it won't affect you. That's such a targeted attack that you have to be pretty important for someone to specifically intercept ebay to get you. And if it wasn't specific to you, but rather the first owner, then it's useless to the attacker; these aren't the tools of drive-by ransom ware purveyors.

Comment: @forest .. Thanks .. I found this article about SRTM
  https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9136520

  Salient points from the article
  1. "Secure Boot" and "SRTM" are different things.
  2. "SRTM" is a facility of the TPM
  3. Secure Boot is a facility of UEFI
  4. They both have the effect of blocking boot sector malware
  5. it's often a good plan to use them together

SRTM = Static Root of Trust for Measurement

I restarted the laptop into the Setup and found
InsydeH2O Setup Utility
Secure Boot - Enabled
TPM Device - Available
TPM State - Enabled

Continued ...

Comment: ... 

I expect that this puts me on the safer side of the line .. BUT ..

The eBay seller was not the original owner. It appears that the seller buys used laptops, puts Windows 10 Home as fresh install. Note that the drive no longer has the "C:\hp" folder (laptop is HP 14-bk061st). 

The seller might then disable Secure Boot and put malware into the firmware flash memory and then re-enable Secure Boot. I think the promises of Secure Boot and TPM can be compromised if someone has physical access to the laptop, as the seller surely had. Unless someone out there knows that this cannot work.

Comment: @dandavis - re: "intercept ebay to get you". No intercept involved. See my comment from a few minutes ago.

Comment: @SGSK Secure boot alone has absolutely no protection against firmware-level malware. It can only protect from OS malware, and even then only to a limited extent. And SRTM with a TPM is secure as long as no one physically tampers with it. Malware tends to lack hands and other instruments required to modify hardware, so for a threat model involving malware persistence, it's enough to assume that hardware itself is not modified.

Answer (score 0):

> "But, what about the firmware?"

Which one? BIOS/UEFI?
HDDs and SSDS have firmware too. There is some public and certainly more non public data around on hacking those. Depending on the laptop there could be more devices with firmware or persistent storage like GPU, NICs ...
A TPM can help you with BIOS and UEFI. afaik it is no solution for the rest as the firmware runs completely independent from the rest of the OS.

> "Does Windows Update make legitimate updates to the firmware?"

No. Usually there some custom tools from the manufacturer of the devices.

> "Is there a way to detect that the firmware contains unauthorized
>   modifications?"

You need to get a legitimate copy for comparison.

> "Is there a way to re-write the flash firmware with factory fresh
>   content?"

Search around here.

Comment: Doesn’t the “legitimate copy” need to be signed, so you know it’s legitimate? Not every laptop manufacturer signs their firmware though, probably. The name-brand business ones probably do though.